# Download CSV file generated players export - OneSignal

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, get, onesignal

How do I download the csv generated by this route: https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/csv_export?app_id=

-I am able to get the s3 link of the file.

-I do a Get Request on the CSV file.  I have tried using the same headers / authorization as the csv_export route and removing it to no avail.

---

w/ the basic auth set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>Basic SOME_KEY_THAT_WORKS_WITH_THE_ROUTE</ArgumentValue><RequestId>SOME_REQUEST_ID</RequestId></Error>
```

w/ the basic auth removed:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>SOME_REQUEST_ID</RequestId></Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

The export file may take a few minutes to generate depending on its size. You should keep trying until you no longer get an error. No authorization is required to download the file.

If it has been longer than 15 minutes and the file is still not available, you should get in touch with OneSignal's support team.

Comment: What should the header look like?

Answer (score 0):

From OneSignal Support, the link returned with that initial route returns the proper url now:

|Hi there. We found a bug in our system that returned the wrong CSV url in some cases. Sorry for the inconvenience.
This issue is now resolved so you should get a valid URL. You can then download the CSV export without any special headers.